# React router does not understand path variable?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router

I have a react applicatie running in a Amazon S3 bucket, it is available here:  This is the homepage of the app, the user can search ships in the search bar.

The app produces a link in the dropdown menu that looks like this:

However when the user clicks on the link you don't see the details page but the user is redirected to this page  without CSS.

Locally is everything working fine.

My route component looks like this:

```
export class Routes extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Route exact path={HOME_PAGE} component={Home}/>          
            <Route path={HOME_PAGE + "/details/:id"} component={Details}/>
            <Route path={HOME_PAGE + "/form/:mode"} component={Edit}/>
            <Route path={HOME_PAGE + "/form/:mode/:id"} component={Edit}/>
            <Route path={HOME_PAGE + "/csvForm"} component={CsvForm}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have build a prefix for the `HOME_PAGE` path that looks like this:

`export const HOME_PAGE = (ENVIRONMENT == "DEVELOPMENT") ? "" : "/url"`

This sets the homepage path for either development or production environment.

I was thinking of an other way to pass the ship id to the details page, maybe with a GET parameter. So the route will look something like this `HOME_PAGE + /details?id=5c335682379b4d7a6ea454a8`.

But I don't know if react-router supports that kind of parameter, maybe someone has a beter solution to solve this problem. Just by playing around on the website, I hope I have given enough information to understand the structure of the site.

Comment: Did you specify your `index.html` file as Error page in amazon s3 settings ?

Comment: I don't think so, I have no acces to the server by the way. Since I am just an intern at the company. So deployment goes by emailing my zipped build folder to the administrator.

Comment: Also use `<Switch>` tag. At `/form/:mode/:id` it should render `Edit` twice. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch . Also x2. Are you using `<Link />` component at dropdown? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: That might be the sollution, I will take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using react router v4, for every Route that you defined, react-router will pass three props:

- Match
- Location
- History

If you would like to access the `params` (which is under `/:someParams`), you can access the `Match` props by using `match.params.someParams`

And if you prefer the query string, you can use the `Location` props by using `location.search` which is a string so that in your case it'll return `?id=5c335682379b4d7a6ea454a8`. You'll have to process the string by using `qs` to get your `id` value.

You can see the detail over here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/route-props

So in your case this would be the solution:

#### On your parent

```
<Route path={HOME_PAGE + "/details"} component={Details}/>
```

#### Your your `Details` Component

```
import qs from 'query-string'

const Details = ({location}) => {
  const {search} = location
  const queries = qs.parse(search) // you should have the query string object
  return (
    <div>{queries.id}</div>
  )
}
```